# JWT: How to get a List of Values from a specific Key in the Claims. C# Asp.Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, jwt, claims

I am using this piece of code to read a single value from the claims in the JWT.

```
return httpContext.User.Claims.Single(x => x.Type == "id").Value;
```

to get the value of this claim:

```
"id": "b6dddcaa-dba6-49cf-ae2d-7e3a5d060553"
```

However, I want to read a key that has multiple values.
But with the same code:

```
return httpContext.User.Claims.Single(x => x.Type == "groups").Value;
```

for this claim:

```
  "groups": [
    "123",
    "234"
  ],
```

I logically get the following error message:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: "Sequence contains more than one matching element"
```

I can't find the corresponding method. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because of [`Single()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.single?view=net-5.0), use [`Where()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=net-5.0) instead of `Single()`

```
return httpContext.User.Claims
          .Where(x => x.Type == "groups")  //Filter based on condition
          .Select(y => y.Value);  // get only Value
```

---

[`Single()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.single?view=net-5.0): It returns a single, specific element of a sequence. *It throws an error if there are multiple elements found which satisfies the condition*

Answer (score 0):

Reference [`ClaimsPrincipal.FindAll(Predicate<Claim>)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.claims.claimsprincipal.findall?view=net-5.0#System_Security_Claims_ClaimsPrincipal_FindAll_System_Predicate_System_Security_Claims_Claim__)

> Retrieves all of the claims that are matched by the specified predicate.

```
IEnumerable<Claim> claims = httpContext.User.FindAll(x => x.Type == "groups");
IEnumerable<string> values = claims.Select(c => c.Value);
return values;
```